# What makes up a Builder Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Hello I have a few questions in regards to the Build Pattern?

1. Why are the instance variables in the main class private?
2. Why is the inner class declared static??
3. Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and repeated?
4. We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is contained within this object?
5. Why is the main constructor private?

```
public class Plank {
    //1. Why are these instance variables private?
    private double widthInches;
    private double heightInches;
    private double thicknessInches;

    //2. Why is this class static?
    public static class Builder {
        //Why are these instance variables private and repeated?
        private double widthInches;
        private double heightInches;
        private double thicknessInches;

        public Builder widthInches(double inches) {

            widthInches = inches;
            //3. What is returned here what object is this referencing?
            return this;

        }
        public Builder heightInches(double inches) {
            heightInches = inches;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder thicknessInches(double inches) {
            thicknessInches = inches;
            return this;
        }
        public Plank build() {
            return new Plank(this);
        }
    }
    //4. Why is this constructor private?
    private Plank(Builder build) {
        widthInches = build.widthInches;
        heightInches = build.heightInches;
        thicknessInches = build.thicknessInches;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what makes a builder pattern, I guess!

Comment: The questions you ask have not much to do with the builder-pattern itself: it are coding rules designed for "good implementation". Please reformulate your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your questions as best as I can in order of enumeration.

## 1. Why are the instance variables in the main class private?

Instance variables in the main class are private for the sake of *access control* to the object's properties. In Java, most *fields* of an object are   private by convention, with public accessors (ie. `Type getField()` and `void  setField(Type field)`) exposed where necessary.

This is because according to object-oriented principles, **the implementation of all behavior should be hidden from view except by the object itself**. In practice, this leads to the ability to override the underlying implementation (say, if you want an encapsulated object to provide storage, or if you want the implementation to require database fetches and updates every time instead of storing a local copy of the data.

## 2. Why is the inner class declared static??

The `Builder` class is a static member of the `Plank` class because it provides the only externally-accessible way to create a `Plank` object. It tightly couples the two classes, since they are dependent on each other.

***IMPORTANT***: You have a very important typo in your code: The `Builder` class should be `public`.

The benefits of doing this means that you can construct a `Builder` and use that to fluently construct a `Plank` bit by bit instead of having a ton of properties passed into a constructor. The `Builder` being static means you can do this to receive a `Plank` with default parameters:

```
Plank p = (new Plank.Builder()).build();
```

## 3. Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and repeated?

These instance variables serve as your **template** for `Plank` objects. By having these configurable one by one, you can construct a `Plank` little by little inside your `Builder`, then pull the trigger and pop out a new `Plank`. The analogy is setting up the parameters of a woodcutting machine, which would then use those parameters to construct one or many identical planks, and would provide sane, usable defaults.

This means you can do the following:

```
Plank.Builder builder = new Plank.Builder();
builder.widthInches(13);
builder.heightInches(2);
// Don't set the thickness; use the default defined in the Builder's constructor.
Plank p1 = builder.build();
Plank p2 = builder.build();
// Now set the thickness to a new value
builder.thicknessInches(14);
Plank p3 = builder.build();
```

## 4. We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is contained within this object?

Ooh, this is one of my favorites. This lets us perform what's called *method chaining*, which is similar to how things like string concatenation and mathematical operations work in the language, but with variables and function calls instead of operators and operands. This lets us do tricks like this:

```
Plank p = (new Plank.Builder())
           .heightInches(13)
           .thicknessInches(14)
           .widthInches(12)
           .build();
```

or this:

```
Plank.Builder builder = (new Plank.Builder())
                         .heightInches(13)
                         .thicknessInches(14)
                         .widthInches(12);
Plank p1 = builder.build();
Plank p2 = builder.build();
```

When coupled with better method names, this can be used to sound like a spoken-word command when read aloud, which is a pattern referred to as a "fluent interface". C#'s LINQ and Enumerables use one of these.

## 5. Why is the main constructor private?

Well, because using a `Builder` is just better! We want to avoid the developer who uses these classes from having ugly syntax, so we keep the ugly bits hidden and inaccessible, keeping fingers away from the gears which make this pattern work, as it were.

What we **DON'T** want is something like this in client code:

```
Plank.Builder builder = new Plank.Builder().heightInches(13);
Plank p1 = new Plank(builder);
```

That's a lot uglier than:

```
Plank p1 = (new Plank.Builder()).heightInches(13).build();
```

## Additions

If you want to clean this up even more, you could make the constructor for `Plank.Builder` private, and provide the following method inside `Plank`:

```
public static Plank.Builder getBuilder() {
    return new Plank.Builder();
}
```

Then, client code would be:

```
Plank p1 = Plank.getBuilder()
                 .heightInches(13)
                 .build();
```

Answer (score 6):

First, read about the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

> Why are the instance variables in the main class private?

Because instance variable should be `private` (or `protected`) to prevent direct manipulation by untrusted code.

> Why is the inner class declared static??

Because the builder needs to be constructed *before* the class being built, i.e. the outer class.

> Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and repeated?

Because (see first answer) and (see second answer).

> We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is contained within this object?

Returning the builder object from setter method allow for [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

> Why is the main constructor private?

So the class can only be instantiated by the builder.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are the instance variables in the main class private?

That's a good default for *any* class implementation - not to reveal the internal details of implementation. This is not specific for the builder pattern.

> Why is the inner class declared static??

Because you need the builder to be created before an instance of the outer class does.

> Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and
>   repeated?

See the first answer in regards to "private". As for "repeated" - not sure what do you mean by that.

> We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is
>   contained within this object?

We return the builder object so that the user will be able to chain calls, i.e.

```
builder.widthInches(3.0)
       .heightInches(2.0)
       ...
```

> Why is the main constructor private?

In order to block access to it from the outside - and force the user to use the builder.

You can [read here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) more about the builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why are the instance variables in the main class private?

In Java, it is a best practice to always make instance variables private.  This is a form of encapsulation.  A class is responsible for its own fields, and any code outside of the class is supposed to access those fields indirectly though public methods (such as Setters and Getters).

2. Why is the inner class declared static??

There are 2 types of nested classes: *static nested classes* and *inner classes*.  In this case, you're using a static nested class because you're accessing it in a static way (i.e. you don't already have an instance of the containing class).

3. Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and repeated?

They're private for the same reason as the main class's instance variables.

4. We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is contained within this object?

The keyword `this` refers the current object instance, which in this case would be a `Builder` object.  Returning the current instance allows the caller to chain calls like

```
Builder builder = new Builder().widthInches(2.0).heightInches(3.0).thicknessInches(1.5);
```

5. Why is the main constructor private?

It's private to force the calling code to use `Builder`.  Even though it's private, nested classes (such as `Builder#build`) can call it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are the instance variables in the main class private?

This follows proper encapsulation. In this case, a `Plank`'s width, height, and thickness should never change once the `Plank` is created. If these fields were public, someone might inadvertently change the size of an existing `Plank`.

In general, many programmers err on the side of making things private and exposing the data via getter and setter methods. This way you as the programmer retain control over the variables within your classes and you can sanitize the data and control read/write access as appropriate.

> Why is the inner class declared static?

A `Builder` instance isn't tied to a specific instance of a `Plank` (or any other object). Not only that, but it *can't* be tied to a specific instance, because the `Builder` is trying to create the instance.

Making it non-static would create an interesting case in which you need a `Plank` to create a `Plank`.

> Why are the instance variables in the inner class private and repeated?

As explained in the previous answer, the `Builder` exists separately from the `Plank` and is created before the `Plank` instance. Thus it needs to have it's own copies of the fields so it can create the plank later.

Again, keeping them private allows the `Builder` to retain full control over these variables, ensuring that users of the `Builder` must interact with the methods in order to properly create a `Plank`.

> We return the Builder Object within the methods what exactly is contained within this object?

The returned `Builder` represents the current state of the `Builder`. Here are some examples:

```
// Calling plankBuilder1.build() would create a Plank with no width, height, or thickness.
Plank.Builder plankBuilder1 = new Plank.Builder();

// Calling plankBuilder2.build() would create a Plank with a height, but no width or thickness
Plank.Builder plankBuilder1 = new Plank.Builder().heightInches(1.0);
```

> Why is the main constructor private?

The `Builder` pattern is intended to replace a constructor. There are myriad reasons that a programmer might find this desirable, but the end result is that you want consumers of this class to use the `Builder` to create instances of your object.

If the constructor were public, then consumers would likely try to use that instead of the `Builder`. Making it private forces them into using the `Builder`.